# Cast ArrayFire Array Data from f64 to f32 in C++

Tags: c++, arrayfire

I have an ArrayFire array of `dtype=f64` that I need to cast to `dtype=f32`. I'm not sure how to do this other than converting to a host array and iterating through doing a `static_cast`. I'm sure there is a better way. I found [`af_cast`](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__arith__func__cast.htm) but it seems to only be a part of the C interface.

```
// Example, double precision array
af::array A_double(100, 1, f64); // f64 = double precision

// Need to cast this to an f32 array somehow...
af::array A_single = cast<f32>(A_double); // <-- something like this?
```

Comment: Can you show some code for context?

Comment: C++ casting can't cast an entire array at once, only one element at a time.  If ArrayFire has this ability it will only be by making a copy of the original.

Answer (score 2):

The answer turned out to be embarrassingly simple. The ArrayFire library has a function called `as` that I did not know about and had overlooked in the documentation.

```
// Example, double precision array
af::array A_double(100, 1, f64); // f64 = double precision

// Cast to an f32 array
af::array A_single = A_double.as(f32);
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://arrayfire.org/docs/classaf_1_1array.htm#a5822c6bdfbf4ff01f23c4417934b924c).

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Anything we could have done better?